# returning html and PHP in a PHP function

Tags: php, html, function

```
function showButton(){                      
?>
  <div class="btn-group dropup">
     <button class="btn <?php echo $strOpportunityStatusColor; ?> btn-sm dropdown-toggle" 
       type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span aria-hidden="true"  ></span><?php echo $strTotalCold."  ". " Cold ". "  ".$display." " ; ?> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button> <br><br>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="height: auto; max-height: 150px;overflow-x: hidden;">
<?php                   
     $cor = get_filtered_opportunities($strClientId, 'Cold');

     foreach ($cor as $filtered) {
        $strOpportunityActivityItemId = $filtered["ActivityItemId"];
        $strOpportunityId = $filtered["OpportunityId"];
        $strOpportunityLeadStatus = $filtered["ActivityItemLeadStatus"];
        $strTitleName = $filtered["TitleName"];
        $strEditionName = $filtered["EditionName"];
        $strFeatureName = $filtered["FeatureName"];
        $strOpportunityValue = $filtered["ActivityItemValue"];                                                          
        $strContactEmail = $filtered["ContactEmail"];
    
        if(!$strTitleName) {
          $strTitleName = 'NO TITLE';
        }
        if(!$strEditionName) {
          $strEditionName = 'No specified edition';
        } else {
          $strEditionName = 'Edition: '.$strEditionName;
        }
                                
        if(!$strOpportunityValue) {
          $strOpportunityValue = 'No specified value';  
        } else {
          $strOpportunityValue = 'Value: £'.$strOpportunityValue;
        }
        ?>
        <li>
          <button type="button" style="margin:2px;" onclick="viewOpportunity('<?php echo $strOpportunityId; ?>','<?php echo $strOpportunityActivityItemId; ?>','<?php echo $strClientId; ?>');" class="btn btn-sm <?php echo $strOpportunityStatusColor; ?>"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-magnifier"></span> <?php echo $strTitleName ; ?></button><br>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
```

I have a function here that holds code a button that holds both HTML and PHP. I want to return all the code and html when calling this function. For now when I call this function it simply echoes out the html but the PHP functionality inside isn't working at all. As the button requires me to come in and out of php, retuning seems to be an issue. How can I return all this working code?

Comment: You should not switch from PHP to HTML mode to begin with here, but assemble your HTML code in a variable, that can be returned at the end. The other alternative would be to use output buffering.

Comment: `isn't working at all`...it's not very clear what this actually means. What were you expecting to happen and what actually happens? So far as I can see it runs a loop and is supposed to generate some buttons containing output of the variables from the PHP. Are you saying there are no buttons created? Or they don't contain the data you expected? It's not clear. And have you done any debugging? We can't see your variable data so we can't predict what the code will actually do when you run it.

Comment: You can do a cleaner solution for this using the output buffer functions vs string concat but as noted, modern day programming has moved on from this technique to some degree. Most are using some kind of javascript/typescript framework (React, Angular, Vue) to manipulate the frontend DOM. I am of the opinion you can do what works for you as long as it's implemented safely. If you are coordinating with a professional team, this will be frowned upon due to many reasons.